# array concatenation giving error in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have two arrays

```
array_1.shape
#(961,300)


array_2.shape
#(961,9)
```

when I am concatenating the whole arrays I am not getting any error:

```
 np.column_stack((array_1,array_2))
```

but when I am concatenating the first element of each, I am getting the error:

```
array_1[0].shape
#(300,)

array_2[0].shape
#(9,)
np.column_stack((array_1[0],array_2[0]))

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

the first element of two arrays are here:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/pP11bkPY

Comment: (300, ) do not have columns .

Comment: `column_stack` turns (n,) shaped arrays into (n,1) shaped before concatenating.  In other words, it turns the 1d inputs into column vectors and tries to join those columns.  The full error message shows the code that does this.

Comment: You are trying to concatenate the first row of each array.  The rows have different sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) instead will prevent this error, and it will give you the intended (309,)-shaped output